# How do I force an assembly to uninstall from the GAC?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, gac

I've developed a simple installation package using WiX that installs an assembly called `WBRT.Configuration` into the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). While the file installs, it is not removed when the package is uninstalled.

I've tried running a command prompt as administrator, used msiexec /x specifying the msi filename and msiexec /x specifying the product code.

With the /l*v switch, there is no error:

`Executing op: ActionStart(Name=MsiUnpublishAssemblies,Description=Unpublishing assembly information,Template=Application Context:[1], Assembly Name:[2])
Executing op: AssemblyUnpublish(,,AssemblyType=1,,AssemblyName=WBRT.Configuration,version="1.0.0.0",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="361AD75BADC53912",processorArchitecture="MSIL",Descriptor=2-(xWui~z@UnhQuo-~Gh>S.OwM9Kim9x0ul%Ore=9)
Executing op: ActionStart(Name=UnpublishFeatures,Description=Unpublishing Product Features,Template=Feature: [1])`

**WiX File element**

`<File Id="filB7155C3E9A241BEAFE09533364964732" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net" Source="$(var.Configuration.TargetDir)\WBRT.Configuration.dll" />`

**MsiAssemblyName table in Orca**

[image: MSIAssemblyName]

**File in the GAC**

[image: File in GAC]

**Version tab of the file in the GAC**

[image: Version]

I'm **completely stumped**. Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, verify that your assembly is not locked by another process
    via gacutil.exe

```
gacutil /u WBRT.Configuration
```

If the above is OK make sure the file parent container has no permanent flag -
    `Permanent="no"`

```
<Component Shared="yes" Permanent="no" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE" >
    <File Id="filB7155C3E9A241BEAFE09533364964732" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net" 
       Source="$(var.Configuration.TargetDir)\WBRT.Configuration.dll" />
</Component>
```

Comment: Gacutil gave the message `Unable to uninstall: assembly is required by one or more applications`. Process Explorer showed what processes were locking the DLL and ended them. The file then uninstalled correctly!

Comment: @AlexAngas : same with me. How to unlock the dependency?

Comment: Finally I delete my dll name key at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Assemblies\Global] and run gacutil /u dllname -> And success. I do not know what is the side effect.

Comment: @Toha, worked for me, then I ran `gacutil -u dllThatIWantedToRemove`

Answer (score 2):

I followed the steps mentioned by [@Mohsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2634046/mohsen-hs) , Remove the registry entry and uninstalled the DLL from GAC to resolve a conflict issue.

[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Assemblies\Global] and run gacutil /u dllname -And success. 
I do not know what is the side effect. It worked for me, then I ran

gacutil -u dllThatIWantedToRemove