# Select data from table throws an error in SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I've get an error when executing a simple query in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
```

Error:

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Unable to find an entry point named 'SetClrFeatureSwitchMap' in DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll'.

It happens with the only table in database which contains coordinates in `DbGeography` format. I can operate with this table via my local SQL Server 2014, but this database is on a remote server, and application does not work.

I have the same version of the database on another server, and there it works.

Everything I found was about Entity Framework, but this error appears inside SQL Server 2012. Also I tried to connect to database with Entity Framework by applying this option: [Entity Framework cannot update database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204990/entity-framework-cannot-update-database/34431276#34431276), but it didn't help.

Is there any way to solve the problem?

This is not a duplicate question because this error does not appear by using EntityFramework. And also I've tried every answer from the related question.

Comment: so wait...You're developing with a newer version of SQL Server than you're deploying to?  I'm going to hazard a guess that this is at least part of your issue.

Comment: @user2366842 the service I'm trying to deploy was written and tested with  MS SQL 2012, and everything worked fine. I have no idea what could be changed.

Comment: @mason why is it duplicate? I've tried that solution, it did not work!